# Apollo single source of truth

Tags: redux, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

redux has the principle of "single source of truth",  and I'm having and hard time figuring how polling fragments from GQL will continue to keep this principle.

TL;DR : Does apollo normalize entities for the whole app, or for each apollo container?

Apollo has his own redux store.
By the architecture graph I see that there is a normalization stage before applying the data into redux.

My questions is: lets say I have a post schema and a user schema.
when polling a post, I pull the post information, and also the author (user schema) name and profile pic.
I have a posts container with apollo.
so I'm **GUESSING** apollo store now has this state :

```
 {
  posts: {
     512 : {
        title: "title"
        content: "big content"
        author: [32]
     }
  },

  users: {
     32 : {
       name: "James"
       profilePic: "YYYYYY"
     }
  }
}
```

but what happens when the user - James, change his name to Julian, and another component, the chat menu component which updates frequently will have the user id : 32 with different name, Julian.
will the posts container will be updates too because of this?
or it will keep displaying out of date data?

Answer (score 0):

Great question!

Your answer can be found here: http://dev.apollodata.com/core/how-it-works.html#normalize

Going to summarize in case the link breaks:

`apollo-client` doesn't store things the way you request it, but rather as a flat structure (and generate an ID for that object based on `id`, `__typename` and keep track of the references between the objects.

When components request those objects it will take the objects from the flattened structure and build it into the requested format.